# Long-polling solution in android native app?

Tags: android

i need to build a app to do live reporting, can you suggest a solution that enables real-time communication? I'd like to go with long-polling this approach.

It will be an Android native app, not a web app.

Is there something already written so I do not need to implement it from very beginning.?

I'm a django, python developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a polling solution but when I needed something like this I created a [foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground) service that creates a persistent socket connection to my server. I then registered with some broadcast receivers to maintain my service, on BOOT_COMPLETED and CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE. This worked better for me then C2DM because I had more control of the system and was virtually real time. C2DM is a fire and forget system and is not guaranteed to be reliable. You will have to manage the socket between changes in connections, and maybe hold some kind of [wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

For a polling solution, you could also build a web server and poll with http requests. This will avoid the need to manage the socket between connection changes but is not a real time solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the receiving end, there is the Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework (Google's implementation of push notifications): http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Note: this requires Android 2.2 and up (~84% of users as of today)